# How to fix dancing button?

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

Consider the following button style:

```css
body {
  padding: 1rem;
}

button {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1rem;
}

button:hover {
  transform: translateY(-3px);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .18);
}
```

```html
<button>kinda shaky</button>
```

When I pointed at border, then the button start dancing!!

[image]

How to fix dancing button?

Comment: remove `translate` from button hover css.

Comment: yeah... I know. but I want to keep `transform` on the hover.

Comment: @mitsuruog: if you want to keep the transform, what are you trying to fix? because transform is the reason that its dancing..

Answer (score 6):

Easy fix is to use a *wrapper* and `display` it as `inline-block`:

```css
body {
  padding: 1rem;
}

span {
  display: inline-block; /* "inline-flex" is ok too */
}

button {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1rem;
}

span:hover > button {
  transform: translateY(-3px);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .18);
}
```

```html
<span><button>kinda shaky</button></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

transform property makes this shaky behavior.

If you want to keep `translate` on hover, then easy fix is to wrap the button with inline block element.

demo on both case is here - [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1hnb6r0v/4/)

Answer (score 1):

This is going to happen with the way you've styled your elements, the browser thinks your button has moved so your mouse leaves it, sending it back to no hover, which then hovers so it moves and so on and so forth.

Theres a few options for work around but one would be: put the button inside a div, have the hover set on the div itself then style it like so

```
div:hover > button{
   transform: translateY(-3px);
   box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .18);
}
```

Alternatively you could work out something with adding padding on the button when hovered, but this will be wonky and may not work the same on different browsers

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add some div to your transform. Try bellow code.

```css
button {
    background: blue;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 1rem;
}

button:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .18);
}

.janjok{
    margin:10px;
}

.janjok:hover{
    transform: translateY(-3px);
    border-bottom:5px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="janjok">
   <button>kinda shaky</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You obviously don't want to move it from the other side of the page.